# Unhide an external button only when multiple indipendent input fields are filled elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show a specific button only when some fields in another form are filled.
Working on wordpress and woocommerce.

These fields come from a plugin that gives me custom fields for woocommerce.
The button is from another plugin about a configurator, normally that button is accessible as soon as you enter the product page, it let's you customize stuff.

Even though these fileds are required I need to make sure customers fill those first, that's why I thought about hiding the customizer button untill all previous fields are filled.

After so many tries i finally found a solution but unfortunately not so scalable

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
        if (
            ($('.collo input[required]').val() != '') &&
            ($('.spalle input[required]').val() != '') &&
            ($('.manica input[required]').val() != '') &&
            ($('.torace input[required]').val() != '') &&
            ($('.vita input[required]').val() != '') &&
            ($('.bacino input[required]').val() != '') &&
            ($('.braccio input[required]').val() != '') &&
            ($('.avambraccio input[required]').val() != '') &&
            ($('.polso input[required]').val() != '') &&
            ($('.camicia input[required]').val() != '')) {
                $(".configure-product").show();
                clearInterval(checkExist);
       }
        else {
            $(".configure-product").hide(); 
       }
    }, 400);
});
```

Is it possible to make it more scalable?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Riccardo,
Are you looking for this ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(".wapf-wrapper").on("keyup", function() {
  var filled = true;
    $(".wapf-wrapper").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            filled = false
        }
    });
    $(".configure-product").toggle(filled);
 });
});
```

[check on codepen](https://codepen.io/neiroc/pen/rNWmjpo)

Comment: I have already changed classes to the correct ones but still I can't explain why isn't working